# Problems with buttons when keyboard comes out in Android

Tags: android, scroll, keyboard

I've read a lot of community responses in order to solve the keyboard problem in android but I'm just not able to solve it.

I would appreciate if someone would to help me. My problem is that everytime the keyboard comes out, all the lower screen buttons merge with the upper ones.

Here is my XML.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:id="@+id/pantallaPrincipalGenerarBackgroundView">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Seleccione dificultad"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <RadioGroup

            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            android:gravity="top|center"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Facil"
                android:id="@+id/FacilButton"

                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Medio"
                android:id="@+id/MedioButton2"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Difícil"
                android:id="@+id/DifícilButton"

                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />


        </RadioGroup>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:id="@+id/longitudText"
                android:hint="Introduce longitud"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <Button
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="115dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Generar"
                android:id="@+id/Generarbutton"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Pass"
            android:id="@+id/passwordText"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:textColor="#ff1024ff"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:shadowColor="#ff69ff00" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Usuario"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/passwordText"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/newUserText"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:hint="Introduzca usuario"
            android:layout_margin="7dp"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout4">

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/newUserText"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Seleccione el servicio"
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_below="@+id/newUserText"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="Guardar"
            android:id="@+id/guardarButton"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Servicios"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/flechaizquierda"
            android:id="@+id/abrirListaServiciosButton"
            android:layout_above="@+id/guardarButton"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/abrirListaServiciosButton"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/abrirListaServiciosButton"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/abrirListaServiciosButton"
            android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/newUserText"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/newUserText">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="SERVICIO"
                android:id="@+id/textoMostrarServicioSeleccionado"
                android:textColor="#ff000000" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/imageMostrarServicioSeleccionado" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/guardarButton"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Salir"
                android:id="@+id/salirycerrarPantallaGenerarButton"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/guardarButton"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/goToSegundabutton"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/goToSegundabutton"
                android:layout_margin="1dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Cancelar"
                android:id="@+id/goToSegundabutton"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/guardarButton"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the resizing of your activity by adding this to your Activity tags in the manifest file:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Comment: I did it, all my activities at the moment are statehiden|adjustResize, if i do adjustPan they won't move but it won't scroll. Notice there is a scrollview.

Comment: @RzvGG other answers suggest `android:isScrollContainer="false"`, you could try that.

Comment: Already tried it, i tried some combinations and nothing is working. If i set adjustPan it is not resizing, that's true, but i'm not able to scroll.

Comment: Yes, definately nothing is working for me, i just have no idea what to do.